# Reverse convertible coupon determination

Tags: option-strategies

I had a question about the coupon level determination for a simple reverse convertible product.
Assuming risk free rates are 4% while premium on short put is 5%, typical text-books would then quote the coupon at 9%.

Can't I expect a slightly higher coupon, by reinvesting the put premium received at inception at the risk free rate ? 4 + 5*1.04 = 9.2 % ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You personally cannot invest the coupon. In fact, you typically don't even see what the value of the short put is on the first place.

If you buy a RC, someone else packages that product for you. Ultimately it's how the structurer defines what you get as the buyer (see [here](https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/78211/54838) for an autocallable; a RC is practically the same without interim payments).

The price of the structure will depend on the cashflows to be expected. If they would quote a lower coupon than 9% in your example, you would just pay less up front for the product.