Can someone explain to me how equity linked autocallable notes are structured and why they're hedged with an autocallable swap OTC?
My basic understanding is that the note is constructed with a zero coupon bond where the discounted amount is used to fund the equity linked return but how does this work exactly?
Also, does the note issuer typically loan the amount to the investor to purchase the note which is why the note is hedged with an autocallable swap rather than options?

Does https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/78211/54838 help? The note is one package. An investors simply buys the structure.

Your answer did help a lot but I'm still struggling to grasp the financing part. If the investor buys the note for 1m, why would the issuer enter into an autocallable swap with a dealer to hedge the risk (and pay interest) vs an autocallable option. What did the issuer do with the 1m from the investor?
